# Freeradius - ограничить пользователя одним сеансом

Tags: ldap, freeradius

Добрый день.

Есть следующая конфигурация :

Машина RADIUS01:

`centos7 + freeradius 3.0.4 + mariadb 10 + galera.`

Машина RADIUS02:

`centos7 + freeradius 3.0.4 + mariadb 10 + galera`

Машина LDAP-MASTER:

`centos7 + 389-fds (ldap).`

SQL-базы реплицируются с помощью  galera.

Авторизация пользователей происходит через LDAP, а аккаунтинг пишется в mysql (пробовал использовать `radutmp`).

Задача: ограничить пользователя одним сеансом.
Как я понял для этого используется флаг `Simultaneous-Use`, который должен проверятся при обработке Accounting-Request `Acct-Status-Type=start`. 
Для этого в /etc/raddb/users:

```
DEFAULT Simultaneous-Use := 1
        Fall-Through = 1
```

в /etc/raddb/clients.conf:

```
client my_net {
   ipaddr = 192.168.0.0/24
   nas_type = other
}
```

в /etc/modukes-config/sql/mysql/queries.conf раскомментированы `simul_count_query` и `simul_verify_query`

Но ничего хорошего не происходит:
пользователь может запрашивать авторизацию много раз и всега получает положительный ответ, `Acct-Status-Type=start` - всегда принимаются (делается запись в таблицу `radacct` - если там есть такая-де запись sql-модуль просто обновляет поля с временем доступа), `checkrad` и `simul_*_query` не вызываются.

Собственно - как ограничить пользователя одним сеансом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась:

В `/etc/raddb/users`:

```
DEFAULT Simultaneous-Use = 1    //(убрать ":")
        Fall-Through = 1
```

Может кто-нть объяснить: в чем разница между `:=`, `=` и `==` ?